# pushOrModify like operator for mongo subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

What I'm trying to do is that if subdoc is exist, update it and otherwise, push new subdoc by only one method.

First, find `{ name: "SweetTown" }` and then,

**If `Bob` is exist, I want to change its reputation to `30`:**

```
Town collection
{ name: "SweetTown", residents: [{ name: "Bob", reputation: 20 }] }
```

should be going to be

```
{ name: "SweetTown", residents: [{ name: "Bob", reputation: 30 }] }
```

**Or not, push `{ name: "Bob", reputation: 30 }` to `residents`.**

```
Town collection
{ name: "SweetTown", residents: [{ name: "Alice", reputation: 140 }] }
```

should be going to be

```
{ name: "SweetTown", residents: [
  { name: "Alice", reputation: 140 },
  { name: "Bob", reputation: 30 }
]}
```

I've searched a lot about this and found some ways that could be the solution like `$addToSet`, `$push` with `$ne` or `upsert` option.

But, I couldn't properly mix those to resolve this problem. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually requires "two" ( or "three" with upsert ) update statements and is one of the very good reasons why "Bulk" operations exist.

```js
db.collection.bulkWrite([
  // Attempt to update the matched element
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { 
      "name": "SweetTown",
      "residents.name": "Bob"
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": { "residents.$.reputation": 30 }    
    }
  },
  // $push the element where not matched
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "name": "SweetTown",
      "residents.name": { "$ne": "Bob" } 
    },
    "update": { 
      "$push": { 
        "residents": { "name": "Bob", "reputation": 30 } 
      }
    } 
  }}
])
```

Or if you actually wanted to include an `"upsert"` for the basic document of `"SweetTown"` then you need to separate out that concern into it's own test:

```js
db.collection.bulkWrite([
  // Attempt to update the matched element
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { 
      "name": "SweetTown",
      "residents.name": "Bob"
    },
    "update": {
      "$set": { "residents.$.reputation": 30 }    
    }
  },
  // $push the element where not matched
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": {
      "name": "SweetTown",
      "residents.name": { "$ne": "Bob" } 
    },
    "update": { 
      "$push": { 
        "residents": { "name": "Bob", "reputation": 30 } 
      }
    } 
  }},
  // Only use $setOnInsert when actually an upsert
  { "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "name": "SweetTown"
      },
      "update": {
        "$setOnInsert": {
           "residents": [{ "name": "Bob", "reputation": 30 }]
        }
      },
      "upsert": true
  }}
])
```

So the general concept there is to **only** apply the [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) action when an `"upsert"` actually occurs. In order to make sure this only happens in this case, the other operations actually looking at the array element are not marked with the `"upsert"` option. That part is on purpose.

Whatever way you look at it, it is only ever possible for **one** of those operations to actually make any modification in the database, as either the element is found or not, or even the document is not found and a new one created.

In no case is it possible to do that sort of operation in a single update statement. However since "Bulk" operations are really only **one** request with **one** response, then as far as your application is concerned then it only needed to talk to the server **once** to have the server try all of these three things and return a response.

For earlier usage of the direct Bulk API, then the alternate syntax is:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// $set matched where existing
bulk.find({ "name": "SweetTown", "residents.name": "Bob" }).updateOne({
  "$set": { "residents.$.reputation": 30 }
});

// $push where not existing
bulk.find({ "name": "SweetTown", "residents.name": { "$ne": "Bob" } }).updateOne({
  "$push": { "residents": { "name": "Bob", "reputation": 30 } }
});

// Attempt to upsert only
bulk.find({ "name": "SweetTown" }).upsert().updateOne({
  "$setOnInsert": {
    "residents": [{ "name": "Bob", "reputation": 30 }]
  }
})

bulk.execute();
```

Comment: I thought it could be resolved with `findOneAndModify`, But this is completely different way by using `bulkWrite` operation. It gave me a lot of opportunities when I would run into problems which seems like that. Thanks.