# Bulk create/add/update of array sub document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, bulk

Update:

Topic is a duplicate but since i was asking for meteor syntax i've taken the example from the other topic and translated here for you :

// $set matched where existing

```
bulk.update({ "name": "SweetTown", "residents.name": "Bob" },{"$set": { "residents.$.reputation": 30 }});
```

// $push where not existing

```
bulk.update({ "name": "SweetTown", "residents.name": { "$ne": "Bob" } },{"$push": { "residents": { "name": "Bob", "reputation": 30 } }});
```

// Attempt to upsert only

```
bulk.upsert({ "name": "SweetTown" },{"$setOnInsert": {"residents": [{ "name": "Bob", "reputation": 30 }]}})
```

---

I have a simple Schema

```
{"_id","user_name":name}
```

I would like to find a way to :

Create the "option array" if it doesnt exist so that the result is :

```
{"_id","user_name":name,"options":[]}
```

If the array already exist just upadte it with the document

```
{"_id","user_name":name,"options":[{"1":10}]}
```

if the document ( "1" in the previous example) already exist just update the document

```
{"_id","user_name":name,"options":[{"1":30}]}
```

If the document ("number") doesnt exist add it the the array

```
{"_id","user_name":name,"options":[{"1":30},{"2":"50"}]}
```

I've been trying to use bulk to do it in multiple queries but it's never really working like i would like :

```
var obj = {user_name:"test",options:[{"1":10}]};
var bulk = Users.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
 // supposed to add the balance array + the first option OR just the first option if balance already exist but it keeps on appending option every time because i have no selector for it
bulk.upsert( { "user_name" : obj.user_name }, { $push : obj.options});
// So i try this :
bulk.update({"user_name": obj.user_name},{ $set:{"options.$.1": obj.options[0]} }); // doesn't work : add  "xnumber" to position #1 of the  options array
```

Lately i've been trying with a combination of addtoset + push with a .find().update() but without success yet.

Can anyone help ?

Ps: i need bulk because i'm doing other work beforehands , but will probably need it to do this aswell anyway.

Comment: Your syntax is off for both the usage of `.upsert()` and also in the `$set` operation you are trying, with both "query" and "update" statements. But the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466295/pushormodify-like-operator-for-mongo-subdocument) explains the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the topic.Syntax is abit off because I'm trying to get the meteor(mongo) syntax so that's not exactly the same i'm trying to translate it right now and will answer if i manage to do it

Comment: I've updated the main post in case anyone ever needs it. One more question how do you actually find if options : "1" exist ? cause on the other topic he is check for the presence of "bob" to set his reputation.

Comment: What I mean by "a bit off" is the driver syntax is actually `bulk.find({ .. }).upsert().updateOne({ ... })` etc, and ditto for other syntax problems. Once you use `.rawCollection()` then everything else has **nothing** to do with meteor any more, and is just all raw driver.

Comment: As for that check, it's actually a bit cruel and worthy of it's own question. The correct way is `{ "options": { "$elemMatch": { "1": { "$exists": true } } } }` using `$elemMatch`. The reason you cannot do `{ "options.1": { "$exists": true } }` is because though `"1"` is the name of your "key", MongoDB thinks you mean the "second" ( n-1 ) array element exists, rather than matching the "key". Which should probably be a tip that you should choose different naming here to avoid such conflicts.

Comment: Actually, the big conclusion here would be to instead do `"options": [{ "position": 1, "value": 10 }]`. In that way you can query with `{ "options.position": 1 }` and actually even have a "consistent index" on `"options.position"` to make queries faster.

Comment: That's true i was a little bit uncomfortable using "1" anyway so i'll change to that